# Spring boot let encrypt issue

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, lets-encrypt

So i have my site on hosting company, and this company support let encrypt certificate, so i generated it and now the site is running with https protocol.My server side(spring boot application web service oriented started on VPS) for this site is on another company. My questions are:

1. How can i use this generated certificate on my server side part,
2. is it possible, what should i do?
3. What i need to provide to the server, and all things that are needed the server to work?

When i was without the certificate everything worked perfect, but right now on the server side i get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

and in the browser i get

```
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR,
```

when I`m trying the get resources from server. 
From the hosting company i can get everything connected to the certificate

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are passing HTTPs traffic to web server which "talks" in plain HTTP.

Normally SSL termination is done on software like `Apache HTTPD` or `Nginx`.

Then you configure it to act as reverse proxy to your actual Spring boot application running in JVM.

You can also configure your JVM webserver (Jetty,Tomcat .. whatever you have) to use your Let's encrypt certificate, but I have doubt that `certbot` will be able to easily renew them.